# Makefile include .depend

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, I have a:

```
include .depend
```

I also have a

```
depend:
  rules for buiding .depend
```

Now, here is the problem, when ".depend" does not exist, I can't run "make depend"; I have to do "touch .depend; make depend"

Is there anyway to tell Make "if .depend does not exist, still allow me to run 'make depend'" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean that you can't run "make depend" because Make balks at trying to include a file that doesn't exist. If you're using GNUMake you can use -include:

```
-include .depend
```

This will include the file if it exists, but continue without error if it doesn't.

(I've heard that sinclude does the same thing in some other versions of Make.)

Comment: avoid this because this is very GNU specific :(